# Find Synonyms of a Word and Rank Synonyms based on its Closeness to the Base Word

Tags: nlp, nltk, wordnet, synonym, thesaurus

Is it possible to find synonyms of a word and rank the synonyms based on its closeness to the base word? Below is the code for finding the synonyms. I wish to give each synonym a rank. How can I do it?

```
import nltk 
from nltk.corpus import wordnet 
synonyms = [] 

for syn in wordnet.synsets("good"): 
    for l in syn.lemmas(): 
        synonyms.append(l.name()) 

print(set(synonyms))
```

Comment: What is your definition of "closeness"? Can you give an example of the output you expect?

Answer (score 4):

WordNet itself does not rank the synonyms. One synset is one class of equivalence. You can try measuring the cosine distance of word embeddings like [GloVe](https://nlp.stanford.edu/projects/glove/) or [FastText](https://fasttext.cc), this can give you some approximation of semantic similarity.

Comment: Or you could measure "closeness" by minimum edit distance, if that is more suitable for you.